# how to generate unique integer id in jsp using current date and time

Tags: jsp, servlets

how to generate unique integer id in jsp using current date and time.
i want something like this 20110414440 where 2011 is year 04 is month 14 is date 4 is current hr 40 is current min.
even though itseems simple i am unable to get it can anyone help me with the code..?
i want to display it in a text box. i am using jsp and servlets

Comment: i think this could work:
long ts = (new Date()).getTime();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmm");
Date date = new Date();
String str = format.format(date);
```

or simply use `date.getTime()` or `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()` it will also be unique in most cases.

---

**Update:-**

```
<%
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmm");
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
String str = format.format(date);
%>
<input type="text" value="<%= str %>"/>
```

or

```
<input type="text" value="<%= (new Date()).getTime() %>"/>
```

or

```
<input type="text" value="<%= Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() %>"/>
```

or

```
<input type="text" value="<%= (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmm")).format(new java.util.Date()) %>"/>
```

Comment: should i have to give <input type="text" name="id" value=<%=SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmm"); Date date = new Date(); String str = format.format(date); %> > how to show the value in  text box

Comment: AddResource.jsp:223:5: SimpleDateFormat cannot be resolved to a type
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmm");
    ^-------------^
AddResource.jsp:223:35: SimpleDateFormat cannot be resolved to a type
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmm");
                                  ^-------------^
AddResource.jsp:224:5: The type Date is ambiguous
    Date date = new Date();
    ^-^
AddResource.jsp:224:21: The type Date is ambiguous
    Date date = new Date();
                    ^-^

i am getting this error .....

Comment: import `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` in your jsp in page tag.

Comment: i am getting this for all the formats The type Date is ambiguous

Comment: <%= Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() %>" this is working fine is it taking only milliseconds i am getting 13 digit num

Comment: <%@ page import="java.lang.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

Comment: for date use java.util.Date. This is showing error beacuse java.sql.* also contains Date class. Let me update my answer to work for you.